# When insert uuid (Type UUID) into mysql report duplicate entry for key PRIMARY

Tags: java, mysql, uuid

In the code, through `UUID post_uuid = uuidGenerator.generate()` generate a `UUID`, then insert into the mysql.

```
   Connection conn = sql2o.beginTransaction();
   UUID postUuid = uuidGenerator.generate();

   conn.createQuery("insert into posts(post_uuid, title, content, publishing_date) values (:post_uuid, :title, :content, :date)")
        .addParameter("post_uuid", postUuid.toString())
        .addParameter("title", title)
        .addParameter("content", content)
        .addParameter("date", new Date())
        .executeUpdate();

   categories.forEach(category -> 
        conn.createQuery("insert into posts_categories(post_uuid, category) VALUES (:post_uuid, :category)")
        .addParameter("post_uuid", postUuid.toString())
        .addParameter("category", category)
        .executeUpdate());

   conn.commit();
   return postUuid;
```

RandomUuidGenerator Class

```
     public class RandomUuidGenerator implements UuidGenerator{

     @Override
     public UUID generate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return UUID.randomUUID();
     }

   }
```

In mysql, the field of `post_uuid` was `CHAR(36)`

[image]

When I run the code, it report a error

[image]

The error points to second insert sql `addParameter("category", category).executeUpdate())`

Comment: it should `post_uuid.toString()` transfer to string?

Comment: How are you generating your uuids?  Also why are you using uuids instead of integers?

Comment: I just post RandomUuidGenerator above. It was tutorial of SparkJava, I change the DB from MySql while it use Postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it said that in table posts_categories it has the duplicate entry for key PRIMARY

Don't make `post_uuid` the primary key of `posts_categories`.
For each element in your collection `categories` you run the INSERT statement with the same `postUuid`.

Answer (score 1):

try using the String value of it

```
 .addParameter("post_uuid", postUuid.toString ())
```

Comment: I have try, but a new problem is that Error in executeUpdate, Duplicate entry `'dd5f5e44-c549-4bb9-b1a4-009bca084028' `for key `'PRIMARY'`

Comment: where does uuidGenerator come from?

Comment: uuidGenerator is a instance of Class UuidGenerator

Comment: what library does it come from?

Comment: just written by myself. It was `return UUID.randomUUID()`

Comment: it said that in table posts_categories it has the duplicate entry for key PRIMARY